# Memory in Tomcat when running Railo/Lucee

Tags: java, tomcat, coldfusion, railo, lucee

Im looking at this [post about Pulling Used PermGen Space Programmatically](http://www.codersrevolution.com/blog/pulling-used-permgen-space-programmatically-in-coldfusionjava) while trying to figure out how to tweak my Railo/Lucee/Tomcat environment arguments and I was wondering if the information that generates can help me?

This is my current output from the code in that post

> Code Cache (Non-heap memory) 4MB / 48MB
>
> Eden Space (Heap memory) 53MB / 67MB
>
> Survivor Space (Heap memory) 4MB / 8MB
>
> CMS Old Gen (Heap memory) 122MB / 1965MB
>
> CMS Perm Gen (Non-heap memory) 40MB / 1024MB

This is from my setenv.sh

```
JAVA_OPTS="-server -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC"
```

This is my current output from `free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3750       1997       1752          0        190       1351
-/+ buffers/cache:        455       3294
Swap:            0          0          0
```

How can I figure out, or what should I use as my starting points when figuring out my JAVA_OPTS?

Comment: Are you trying to solve a particular issue, e.g an out of memory error of some description?

Comment: Just trying to understand JAVA_OPTS and optimal settings. I've had a few instances where the server would come unresponsive and need restarting so I wanted to ensure I had the best settings

Comment: I don't think there is any such thing as the "best" settings for the JVM, it entirely depends on the application. I've seen Kai Koenig (@agentk on twitter) do several talks on the subject, here are the slide decks http://www.slideshare.net/AgentK/jvm-isyourfriend - http://www.slideshare.net/AgentK/garbage-first-and-you - the second is newer and up-to-date with how Java 8 works.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The problem I have is that I've never really dealt with (too seriously) the JVM settings. Just something I need to sit down to understand a bit more.